# Subrings of ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism, and suppose that $R$ and $S$ are rings with identity. 
Would $S' = \{r \in R\quad|\quad \phi(r) = 1_s\}$ be a subring of *R*?

More generally, how do subrings work for ring homomorphisms?

Comment: $r_1, r_2 \in R$ in the mentioned set then $\phi(r_1+r_2)=\phi(r_1)+\phi(r_2)= 1_s+1_s\neq 1_s$ hence the set isn't closed under addition and not a ring homomorphism

Answer (score 1):

A subring should contain the zero element; does $\{r\in R\mid \phi(r)=1_S\}$ contain the zero element of $R$? We should also have $\phi(0_R)=0_S$ by definition of a ring homomorphism, so we would then have to have $1_S=0_S$. There is only one ring $S$ which has this property, the "zero ring".

Comment: {r $\in$ R | $\phi$(r) = 1<sub>s</sub>} does not contain the zero element of R. So by def is it not a subgroup?

Comment: Also, is {r $\in$ R | $\phi$(r) = 1<sub>s</sub>} an additive subgroup of S that is closed under multiplication?

Comment: $\{r \in R \mid \phi(r)=1_S\}$ is not a subset of $S$ so it can't be an additive subgroup of $S$. It's also not an additive subgroup of $R$  as it doesn't contain $0_R$ unless $S$ is the zero ring.

Answer (score 0):

> More generally, how do subrings work for ring homomorphisms?

The image of a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R\to S$ is a subring of $S$. However, here you're asking if the preimage $\phi^{-1}(1_S)$ is a subring of $R$. As noted in other answers, unless $S$ is the zero ring, the set $\phi^{-1}(1_s)$ doesn't contain $0_R$, so it's not a subring of $R$. And unless $\phi$ is injective, it's not even a well defined function.

The structures that are preserved by preimages of homomorphisms are (left/right/twosided) ideals. Hence if $I$ is an ideal of $S$, then $\phi^{-1}(S)$ is an ideal of $R$.

But be careful, the image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism need not be an ideal. However, if $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $\phi(I)$ will be an ideal of $S$ whenever $I$ is an ideal of $R$.